# Validation error when empty <p:calendar mask="true"> is submitted on blur

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

When I submit a PrimeFaces 5.2.6 `<p:calendar mask="true">` in a JSF 2.2 form by button click with no custom validator, an empty value is valid. But if I submit it with `<p:ajax event="blur">` like below,

```
<h:form>
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" />
    <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true">
        <p:ajax event="blur" />
    </p:calendar>
</h:form>
```

then I get the below validation error?

> '__/__/____' could not be understood as a date.

The calendar value is not set to `required=true`. Why is the behaviour different?

Comment: Can't reproduce based on information so far with PF 5.2. [Post a real MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

Comment: I made a mcve here and updated the question.

Comment: And post PF version info please

Comment: I am using Mojarra 2.2.12 and Primefaces 5.2.6 and OmniFaces 2.1.

Comment: Reproduced with 5.2. I edited the question to show a real MCVE.

Comment: Is this a bug or works as designed?

Comment: Ok....I add an issue in github of PF

Comment: Sounds similar: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/324